# Optimizing bash script that extract substring based on MAC address matching

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Client requires 50 CentOS 7 Hostname to be named based on NIC MAC address:

currently I combined below bash script but seems a lot of optimization can be done, the script will be launched on Image first boot only, it must be stable and tight:

```
for i in `ip a |awk '/ether/ {print toupper($2) "_"}' | sed -r 's/:/-/g'`; do grep -i $i* MAC_HOST | awk -F _ '{print $2}'; done
```

MAC_HOST contents:

```
22-8A-07-4F-16-A8_BT001
22-8A-07-5C-0F-58_BT002
22-8A-07-5C-0F-5B_BT003
22-8A-07-5D-D1-3A_BT004
22-8A-07-5D-D1-3D_BT005
22-8A-07-5D-D1-4C_BT006
22-8A-07-5D-D1-52_BT007
22-8A-07-5D-D1-58_BT008
22-8A-07-5D-D1-5B_BT009
22-8A-07-5D-D1-5E_BT010
22-8A-07-5D-D1-61_BT011
22-8A-07-5D-D1-67_BT012
22-8A-07-5D-D1-7C_BT013
22-8A-07-5D-D1-82_BT014
22-8A-07-5D-D1-8E_BT015
22-8A-07-5D-D1-91_BT016
22-8A-07-5E-2F-4D_BT017
22-8A-07-5E-2F-5C_BT018
22-8A-07-5E-2F-65_BT019
22-8A-07-5E-2F-7D_BT020
22-8A-07-5F-36-65_BT021
22-8A-07-5F-36-9B_BT022
22-8A-07-5F-36-A1_BT023
22-8A-07-5F-36-A4_BT024
22-8A-07-5F-36-A7_BT025
22-8A-07-5F-36-AA_BT026
22-8A-07-5F-36-AD_BT027
22-8A-07-5F-36-B0_BT028
22-8A-07-5F-36-B3_BT029
22-8A-07-5F-36-B6_BT030
22-8A-07-5F-36-BC_BT031
22-8A-07-5F-D8-0B_BT032
22-8A-07-5F-D8-0E_BT033
22-8A-07-5F-D8-11_BT034
22-8A-07-5F-D8-14_BT035
22-8A-07-5F-D8-17_BT036
22-8A-07-5F-D8-1A_BT037
22-8A-07-5F-D8-1D_BT038
22-8A-07-5F-D8-20_BT039
22-8A-07-5F-D8-26_BT040
22-8A-07-5F-D8-29_BT041
22-8A-07-5F-D8-2F_BT042
22-8A-07-5F-D8-32_BT043
22-8A-07-5F-D8-35_BT044
22-8A-07-5F-D8-38_BT045
22-8A-07-5F-D8-3B_BT046
22-8A-07-5F-D8-3E_BT047
22-8A-07-5F-D8-41_BT048
22-8A-07-5F-D8-44_BT049
22-8A-07-5F-D8-47_BT050
```

**note**: append below "before ;done" to write the found Hostname. I remove it so no one overwrite his/her hostname by mistake.

> | cat >> /etc/hostname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this does what you want and it eliminates all shell looping and a lot of processes:

```
ip a | awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} /ether/{gsub(/:/, "-", $2); print a[toupper($2)]}' FS=_ MAC_HOST FS=" "  -
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}`

  This reads in the contents of the first file, MAC_HOST, and stores it in associative array `a`.

  Note that, regardless of how many interfaces are returned by `ip a`, the file MAC_HOST is read only once.  Further, associative arrays have fast look-up.
- `/ether/{gsub(/:/, "-", $2); print a[toupper($2)]}`

  This selects the lines containing `ether` and processes the second field
- `FS=_ MAC_HOST FS=" "  -`

  This sets the field separator to `_` when reading MAC_HOST and then sets it to a space when reading stdin (which comes from `ip a`).

  Note that, in awk, `FS=" "` is [a special case](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html#Default-Field-Splitting): it means that any sequence of one or more whitespace characters is treated as a field separator.

#### Multiline version

The same code, when spread over multiple lines, is:

```
ip a | awk '

  FNR==NR{
    a[$1]=$2
    next
  }

  /ether/{
    gsub(/:/, "-", $2)
    print a[toupper($2)]
  }
  ' FS=_ MAC_HOST FS=" "  -
```

#### Variation: ignoring non-matching MAC addresses

What do we do when `ip a` returns a MAC address that is not listed in MAC_HOST?  The version above prints a blank line.  The version below prints nothing when the MAC_HOST entry is missing:

```
ip a | awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {b=""} /ether/{gsub(/:/, "-", $2); b=a[toupper($2)]} b {print b}' FS=_ MAC_HOST FS=" "  -
```

As an example, the fake input here provides two MAC addresses, one in MAC_HOST, and one not:

```
$ printf 'ether 22:8a:07:5f:36:a4\n\nether 22:8a:07:5f:36:a5\n\n' | awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {b=""} /ether/{gsub(/:/, "-", $2); b=a[toupper($2)]} b {print b}' FS=_ MAC_HOST FS=" "  -
BT024
```

To use the above to overwrite `/etc/hostname`:

```
ip a | awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {b=""} /ether/{gsub(/:/, "-", $2); b=a[toupper($2)]} b {print b}' FS=_ MAC_HOST FS=" "  - >/etc/hostname
```

Comment: PCs got 3 NICs, when I ran your script I got 3 output lines (one contain HOST name, other two empty), in my script it return only single line that match valid NIC address. can you adjust your script so it only return matching result?

Comment: hmm, the update prints valid host twice :( ex: (BT1049\nBT1049)

Comment: Great! it works but i changed "<%s>" to "%s" :) Amazing work! now how to write the output to /etc/hostname instead of '-'?

Comment: Update Works perfect now. how to write the output to /etc/hostname instead of '-'?

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Do you want to overwrite `/etc/hostname` or append to it?

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Just add `>/etc/hostname` to the end of the command, as in the last command in most recent update.